# Modify CSS class on specific pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, overrides, class-extensions

I would like to modify CSS styling to some of my pages, and override the default template styling.

By default, I have this class (`.article-intro-image`) on my template css with some parameters (for example `border-radius: 3px;`)

But just in ONE page attached to a menu item, I'd like to change the parameter to `border-radius: 10px;`

How can I do that without affecting all of the website?

I guess it can be done with "page classes" in the menu item editor, under the "Page display" tab, but I can't figure out how to change/edit the class so it doesn't affect the rest of the web.

---

Thanks mickmackusa, but still doesn't work. I add the class you told me, but when I force to reload my web the images are still affected by the general class:

```
.article-list .article .article-intro-image, .article-list .article .article-featured-video, .article-list .article .article-featured-audio, .article-list .article .article-feature-gallery {
    margin: 0px 20px 60px 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
```

Of course, I tried to put on  "Page display" tab this class too (just in case), but don't work. Any other sugestion?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom class i.e. *.alt-image* and define the CSS in your template as follows

```
.alt-image .article-intro-image img {border-radius: 10px !important}
```

Then you simply add your class in the menu item editor, page display tab in the "Page Class" field.
This will add the class to the `<body>` tag of the item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your template css write:
.page_class .article-intro-image {border-radius: 10px;}
See [Descendant Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Comment: Did you clear browser cache?

Comment: Yes I did, and still no works

Comment: Can you see the newly inserted class in the browser source code?  
Does your template contain an override for this file: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php. Maybe you can post the code. Sometimes it's a small thing. For example, a missing space. The latter causes the two classes "class1" and "class2" to become one: "class1class2"